# how do I use cy.lightouse() to URL which required log in first

Tags: cypress, lighthouse

In my cypress(version 13.6.1) automation test I am trying to use cy.lighthouse() to my landing page URL (https://**/*/dashboard) after log in page, but when lighthouse opens tab, it scans first login page only. is there a way to carry a session or login with cy.lighthouse() on landing URL? thanks

tried looking for solutions but no luck